# Keycloak wait for database connection in standalone mode

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I am running Keycloak on the standalone configuration on wildfly. As database I use MSSQL on a different server than Keycloak. The problem now is that on similar startup the SQL Server needs longer to boot. That causes the Keycloak Service to crash because Wildfly couldn`t connect to the database till deployment.

I already added

```
<validation>                   
   <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
   <background-validation>true</background-validation>
   <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
</validation>
```

to the Datasource. This helped to reconnect if Keycloak is already running and the Database reboots but not on startup.

Is it possible that the Wildfly Server retries to connect to the Database when deploying Keycloak or is there another workaround?

Comment: Duplicate question, however also no satisfactory answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60530557/11011452